# Android : Combining xml file and custom view

Tags: android, xml

What I want to make is that there is two buttons in left side, and imageView on the right side. The buttons activate the camera or bring a photo from the gallery and display it on the imageView. Also, if user touch the image, then a rect shape is following the move of user.

I made a xml file that contain the buttons and imageView.
Then, I made a custom view for the rectangle shape using canvas.

What I was thinking is set touchListener on the imageView and according to the coordinates, app generate the rectangle on the canvas that overlapped on the imageView.

**Here is my question, Can I use both a xml file and custom view at the same time? That means those two things can be overlapped?**

I tried

```
v = new DrawingTheBall(this); // v is my custom view
setContentView(v);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

no errors but, only the first called one appears.

If the overlapping is impossible, then should I just put the buttons and imageView in the custom view class?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use layout resource from XML and custom views created programmatically together.
For this you need to:

1. Specify view holder for custom view in XML and give it an ID (it can be root layout). For example:

   `<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">`
2. `setContentView(R.layout.xml_resource);`
3. Find your custom view container:

`LinearLayout custonViewContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);`

4. Add custom view to container:

`custonViewContainer.addView(view);`

That's pretty much it!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it right away!  You are a life saver~

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your custom view in an XML layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.package.DrawingTheBall
        android:id="@+id/drawingTheBall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```